# javascript: Getting "DOM Exception 9" while creating custom event

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap to develop an android app. in the **index.html** I load a js file like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/loading.css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/readImages.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onReadImage(event) {
        //do something
    }
    document.addEventListener("onReadImage", onReadImage, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--
  .....
-->
</body>
</html>
```

**readImages.js**

```
// Some codes

window.readImageEvent= document.createEvent("readImageEvent"); // line 4
readImageEvent.initEvent("onWeddingCakesRead", true, true); 

//Some functions

readImageEvent.images = data;
document.dispatchEvent(readImageEvent);
```

but when I check LogCat, I see this error:

**Uncaught Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9 at file:///android_asset/www/scripts/readImages.js: 4**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found out the problem.

I changed the below code:

```
window.readImageEvent= document.createEvent("readImageEvent");
```

to:

```
window.readImageEvent= document.createEvent("Event");
```

Because "readImageEvent" is not a proper event type. [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent) could be so useful
about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent)

> The createEvent method is deprecated.

I guess, you can try something like this:

```
var readImageEvent = new CustomEvent(
    "onReadImage",
    {
        detail: {
            images: data
        },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    }
);
document.dispatchEvent(readImageEvent);
```

More information about usage, compatibility, etc can be found [**HERE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Event/CustomEvent)

Comment: This is only true for mozilla. Android does not support CustomEvent, nor IE.

Comment: @Miguel there is a Polyfill right after Browser compatibility table.

Comment: And the polyfill is not supported in some android mobile with document.createEvent('CustomEvent') --> DOM Exception 9 (in Browser Compatibility, Mobile you will see that Mozilla has placed ? in every browser)

Comment: @Miguel The original error can be reproduced in any browser. The question is tagged with `javascript` also, so it does not refer **only** to Android compatibility.

Comment: I think your answer is not correct as the questions says that is developping Phonegapp app for android: some of them they use DOM level 2, where CustomEvent is not defined, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent) in Notes section and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings)